# python regex split at last occurance of special characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to split below and only keep sub text   `Test results don't match for id`
from   `[error][test][new] Test results don't match for id 1911`

I used below to get number out `re.split(r'\d+',  x)[0].strip()` but I want to get `[error][test][new]` out too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `re.split()`, use `re.search()` with lookarounds.

```
x = "[error][test][new] Test results don't match for id 1911"
match = re.search(r'[^]\d]*(?=\d*$)', x)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

The lookahead matches optional digits at the end of the string, and `[^]\d]*` matches a sequence that doesn't contain digits or `]` before that.